# How to disable multi-touch on my mobile web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not looking for a way to prevent zooming. I'm looking for a way to completely stop detecting multiple touches. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: I'd prefer some sort of meta tag magic, instead of checking the length of `event.touches` on each `touchstart` or wherever I'm using it.